# Javascript function behaving unpredictably

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I have am working on a web site in which I am trying to display the distance between the user's location and a specific location whose coordinates are taken from a database. I am using php to retrieve values from a database and calling a javascript function that calculates the distance between the user's location and the coordinates retrieved from the db. Although the function is working alright, I am getting unpredictable results. That is, if the distance function is called 10 times with 10 different coordinates, the result is displayed only for some of the calls. And there is no specific pattern. That is, a set of coordinates that did not have an result displayed on the first run, get a distance displayed on the second run. And the chaos continues each time. I doubt what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var latLngA;
function getLocation(coordinates,call_number) {
    //alert("Entering with coordinates " + coordinates + " and call number " + call_number);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            if(call_number == 0){
                latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            }   
            var latlong = coordinates.split(",");
            var latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1]));
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, latLngB);
            distance = (distance/1000).toFixed(2);
            var table = document.getElementById('venue_list');
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            //alert(distance);
            rows[call_number].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML = distance;
        },
        function() {
            alert("Geo-location not supported!");
        }
    );
</script>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $name = $row['NAME'];
                        $img = $row['IMAGE_SRC'];
                        $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
                        $location = $row['LOCATION'];
                        $coordinates = $row['COORDINATES'];

                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>map_function('{$addr}','{$name}','{$img}','{$i}');</script>";
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img.".jpg"?>" height="100" width="100">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <?php echo $name?>
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:none;">
                                    <?php echo $location?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>getLocation('{$coordinates}','{$i}');</script>";?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    <?php
                        $i=$i+1;
                    }
?>
```

I am relatively new to javascript and hence cannot understand what is going wrong. Looking forward to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: How is variable `$i` initialized? And where is function `map_function()`?

Comment: just before the while loop starts, as $i=0; It keeps a count on the number of iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem due to asynchronous nature of `getCurrentPosition()` function. It happens that variable `latLngA` could be undefined because `getCurrentPosition()` is not called in the sequence which you expect.

This can be seen using some debugging messages. Here is the sequence of messages I got for loop with 5 coordinates:

```
getLocation ... 
call_number: 0 
coordinates: 45,13 
getLocation ... 
call_number: 1 
coordinates: 45.5,13.5 
getLocation ... 
call_number: 2 
coordinates: 46,14 
getLocation ... 
call_number: 3 
coordinates: 46.5,14.5 
getLocation ... 
call_number: 4 
coordinates: 47,15
```

And this is sequence of how `getCurrentPosition()` is called (completely out of order):

```
getCurrentPosition call_number: 3 
["46.5", "14.5"] 
latLngA: undefined 
latLngB: (46.5, 14.5) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'k' of undefined %7Bmain,geometry%7D.js:14

getCurrentPosition call_number: 1 
["45.5", "13.5"] 
latLngA: undefined 
latLngB: (45.5, 13.5) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'k' of undefined %7Bmain,geometry%7D.js:14

getCurrentPosition call_number: 4 
["47", "15"] 
latLngA: undefined 
latLngB: (47, 15) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'k' of undefined %7Bmain,geometry%7D.js:14

getCurrentPosition call_number: 0 
O {k: 45.548058999999995, A: 13.730187999999998, toString: function, j: function, equals: function…}
 22369562-php-coordinates.html:36
["45", "13"] 
latLngA: (45.548058999999995, 13.730187999999998) 
latLngB: (45, 13) 
distance: 83.63 

getCurrentPosition call_number: 2 
["46", "14"] 
latLngA: (45.548058999999995, 13.730187999999998) 
latLngB: (46, 14) 
distance: 54.50
```

So, solution is to change code to get starting position `latLngA` first and then start the loop.